# cuda-gdb crashes mac on second cudaMalloc call

Tags: cuda

I am trying to use cuda-gdb, but it consistently hangs my entire machine
which is a MacBook Pro runnning OS X 10.6.8. I am using the latest Cuda 4.0 tools.
The weird thing is that it hangs on the second call to cudaMalloc. Below
is a snippit from "Cuda By Example:"

```
#define N   10
....
int main( void ) {
  int a[N], b[N], c[N];
  int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

  // allocate the memory on the GPU
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(int) ) );
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_b, N * sizeof(int) ) );
  ...
```

Too bad. I really want to use cuda-gdb. Anyone successfully using cuda-gdb on a Mac?

Comment: do you have access to a linux machine ? cuda-gdb on macosx is fairly new and could have some bugs around

Comment: Yes, I have access to a desktop Linux box with Cuda -- I can't carry it to the coffee shop though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success with it running on OS X but I ran it on >console mode. In the terminal it wasn't so good. Breakpoints freeze the display... Don't remember if it also froze on errors but I think so. In console no problems with the debugger.

Comment: Hmmm.. doesn't make sense, but I'll try it out. Thanks.